# What is a mixture ratio of propellant?

Tags: propulsion

I am a little confused, is the mixture ratio of a propellant Fuel/Oxidizer or Oxidizer to Fuel ratio?

Answer (score 8):

The convention is Oxidizer / Fuel.

> Mixture ratio is defined as the mass flow of oxidizer divided by the
>   mass flow of fuel.

[source](http://www.braeunig.us/space/propuls.htm)